# I need to get my WAMP working. I have two of three services active. Error message is below. (I ran a test)

Tags: windows, wamp, wampserver

```
***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====


Test for TCP
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 seems not actually used.
Unable to initiate a socket connection
Error number: 10060 - Error string: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.


--- Do you want to copy the results into Clipboard?
--- Press the Y key to confirm - Press ENTER to continue...
```

Comment: Did you start WAMPServer? This is basically saying that Apache is not running.

Comment: Have you looked at the error logs? `c:|wamp64\logs` or the Event Viewer!!